# Given a randomly selected spring is not defective. find the probability that it was produced either by machine A or B.

Tags: probability

machine A produces 35%, B 25% and C 40% springs. defective springs produced by A,B,C respectively are 3%,6%,5%. Given a randomly selected spring is not defective. find the probability that it was produced either by machine A or B.

i just don't get the a or b part? i already found P(A|not defective) and P(B|not defective) as 0.355 and 0.246 respectively.

Comment: Use Bayes’ theorem.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at both links [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and for formatting [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Add your own efforts on this to avoid downvotes.

Comment: i just don't get the a or b part? i already found P(A|not defective) and P(B|not defective) as 0.355 and 0.246 respectively.

Comment: @unlimited Just add them both as the events are independent.

Comment: well ok.  i still dnt get why we are just adding them.

Comment: @Rohan Independent? Don't you mean something like "mutually exclusive"?

Comment: @drhab Yes, Sorry, My bad...

Comment: Since the spring was produced by one of A, B, or C, it was produced by A or B if and only it if was not produced by C. $P(A \text{ or }B|\text{not defective}) = 1 - P(C|\text{not defective})$.